# Exsheets and pythontex compatibility

Tags: python, exsheets

I am using **exsheets** and **pythontex** packages in order to make a book of exercises.
I have noticed that `pycode` environment cannot be used inside `question` (or `solution`) environment of exsheets. However, `\pyc` command works normaly within `question`.

The easiest workaround is to write `pycode` outside of `solution` and, in nutshell, that works for me. However, I would like to understand the reason behind this limitation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
        \begin{pycode}
         i_Go = J_L * J_M
        \end{pycode}
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

egreg's answer covers most of the details. Here is a little additional information.

The `lstquestion` and `lstsolution` environments allow listings, by writing environment contents to an auxiliary file and then reading back the auxiliary file at the appropriate point. Since the environment is saved as a file rather than captured as a macro argument, verbatim material works fine. The same approach could be applied to allow `pycode` and similar environments to function. You would need versions of `question` and `solution` that write their contents to an auxiliary file rather than using `\NewEnviron`. This is essentially the same approach that `beamer` takes with its `fragile` option.

As egreg has noted, `\verb` wouldn't work within a `question` or `solution` environment. This might raise the question of why `\pyc` and similar pythontex commands *do* work, since in general they need verbatim arguments. The answer is that `\pyc` works very differently from `\verb`. `\pyc` and similar commands use `\scantokens` to retokenize their arguments, which essentially restores the arguments to verbatim status. However, since the arguments are initially tokenized when the contents of the environment is read as a macro argument, this approach fails if the argument to `\pyc` contains a `#` or `%` character, or an unmatched brace. (I have some ideas about working around this in a future version of pythontex with a properly defined `\#`, `\%`, `\{`, and `\}`.)

That explains how something like `\pyc{...}` works, where the argument is delimited by curly braces. The case where another character is used (for example, `\pyc/.../`) is a little trickier. `\pyc` takes the first delimiting character and, on the fly, creates a macro that will capture everything until the character appears again. Then it invokes this new macro to actually capture the argument. This makes the argument-capturing mechanism essentially catcode-independent (again, with the exception of `#`, `%`, and unmatched braces).

Answer (score 5):

The `question` and `solution` environments use internally the  `__exsheets_questions_internal:` and `__exsheets_solution_internal:` environments that are defined with `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package.

The contents of an environment defined with `\NewEnviron` is absorbed as a macro argument, which makes any verbatim-like command or environment illegal inside it.

You'd get the same problem with `\verb` or `verbatim` in a `question` or `solution` environment.

The package documentation discusses the problem in Part III, where the `exsheets-listing` subpackage is described. Maybe something like that can be done also for allowing `pycode` environments, but the syntax of `lstquestion` and `lstsolution` doesn't seem like the better for complex usage.

Comment: Exactly: `lstquestion` only is a *Notlösung* (as we say in Germany...)

Answer (score 1):

[clemens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299534/using-cprotect-and-environments-with-multiple-arguments#comment915155_299534) is working on a successor of exsheets, xsim, in which this problem is fixed. The xsim package is already on [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim) and shipped with TeXLive and MiKTeX.

The following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
\begin{pycode}
i_Go = 2
\end{pycode}
\py{i_Go}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```