# Using cprotect and environments with multiple arguments

Tags: environments, verbatim, exsheets

Is there a way to use the `cprotect` package's `\cprotEnv` command to use verbatim inside environments that have optional or multiple arguments?

My motivation for this question: I am working with `exsheets`, and want to use `\cprotEnv` so I can use `pythontex`'s `pyblock` and `pycode` inside the `exsheet`'s `question` environment.

Here's an example that shows the problem. Note that the question's subtitle and point value get messed up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\SetupExSheets{headings=block-subtitle}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[subtitle = Codeless Question]{10}
A question without code, worth 10 points. Subtitle and point values are in correct place.
\end{question}

\cprotEnv
\begin{question}[subtitle = Codeful Question]{15}

Now with PythonTeX:
\begin{pyblock}
print("hello, world!")
sum = 0
for j in range(0,100)
    sum += j
print(sum)
\end{pyblock}

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: I disagree that this question is a duplicate of [Exsheets and pythontex compatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/exsheets-and-pythontex-compatibility) . The linked question is about using `PythonTeX` with `exsheets`. Although using `PythonTeX` with exsheets is the motivation for my question, I am asking specifically about the `cprotect` package. The linked question (and answers therein) do not mention the `cprotect` package at all.

Comment: It will, I think, work in cases where you use a plain `\begin{question}...\end{question}` i.e. with no arguments to the environment. At least, it works for me as far as I can tell - it looks nothing like yours, but just the same as it looks outside the `question` environment. (`?? PythonTeX ??` in bold in both cases, so I guess that's right.) But I don't think you can use `\cprotEnv` with something that takes more than one argument i.e. just the body of the pseudo-environment.

Comment: For what it's worth: [I'm currently working on a successor to `exsheets`](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2017/02/improving-exsheets/) which will natively support any verbatim material inside exercises and solutions…

Comment: @clemens Exciting! I look forward to trying it.

Comment: @cfr Perhaps you should post that as an answer? (it's correct, and there's no other solution – using something other than `\cprotEnv` would be a workaround because OP specifically asked about that command.) (besides about the `?? PythonTeX ??` part you need to run PythonTeX and another pass of LuaLaTeX, but it doesn't really matter.)